# Как отследить нажатие кнопки like iframe-версии?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-api

Есть ли возможность (jQuery, JS)? Или как отключить вывод комментариев после нажатия на *Like XFBML* версии кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
       alert('лайкнуто')
    }
);
```

Так кэпчурится нажатие на лайк-кнопку